# C# print to Xerox with custom Feed Edge

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I am using [System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.7.2) to print to network printer.
Because I need to use as much of space as possible, I need to change default settings of [Feed Edge](http://www.office.xerox.com/userdoc/FAM_O2/driverhelp/db_tray_5_bypass_e.html) from **Long Edge** to **Short Edge**.

I am using [System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.printdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2) to select printer.

Comment: I think it's less to do with "System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument" and more to do with formatting the document.

Comment: @PratikGhag The document is me drawing to it using System.Drawing.Graphics so there is no formatting from me.
Reason why I care about it is because I notices another ~1cm on which I can paint (and it will print OK).